# Print JSON preserving HTML tags

Tags: php, json

I want to write a simple WP plugin which will print some post data. Currently, I create an array, like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'content' => get_the_content()
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Problem is - HTML in `get_the_content` is getting parsed. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually in this particular problem, since I need JSON, the simplest and the best way is to post `header`, like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This will cause application to treat the file (either named `aaa.json` or `index.php`) as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should solve your problem.

It will replace html-specific characters with their "entity codes". F.ex. `<` becomes `&lt;`, etc.

And when printed to a page, these entities will be displayed as they were originally, except they won't be accepted as part of an html tag.